# Is gcc missing an opportunity to optimize ctor initializer lists?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, compiler-optimization, clang++

Consider these two structs (legal C++11 and beyond):

```
struct A {
    unsigned int a = 5;
} a;

struct B {
    unsigned int b;
    B() : b(5) {}
} b;
```

[As far as I understood](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization), `a` and `b` should produce exactly the same code.

clang (8.0.0) does what I expect and produces the following assembly:

```
a:
        .long   5                       # 0x5
b:
        .long   5                       # 0x5
```

g++ (9.1) seems to miss this optimization opportunity:

```
_GLOBAL__sub_I_a:
        mov     DWORD PTR b[rip], 5
        ret
b:
        .zero   4
a:
        .long   5
```

[See the code on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hE3I10). What g++ compiles to is equivalent to this:

```
struct C {
    unsigned int c;
    C() { c = 5; } // initialize + assign
} c;
```

which I would not expect, especially because I compile with `-O3`. Is this an "optimization bug"?

Comment: Which gcc version? And does it also happen if you use the {} syntax, i.e.: "struct A {
    unsigned int a{5};
} a;" ?

Comment: It would only be a "bug" if the behaviour was demonstrably different from what the standard requires, which it is not.   Compiler optimisation is a quality of implementation concern, not something that all compilers are required to do identically.    In comparing clang and g++, it is a fair bet that each supports some set of optimisations better than the other.

Comment: @Peter I updated my question... of course I'm not talking about a bug in the original sense, more in the sense of an missing optimization opportunity! Thanks for pointing out

Comment: @MartinHierholzer I've updated the question and added version numbers. It's visible in the godbolt link as well! Thanks for pointing out! Btw: Interesting that g++ also has problem when using the `{}` syntax... is this a known problem?

Comment: @andreee thanks and, err... forget about the second part of my comment ;-) I thought the problem was with struct A, not with struct B. Of course this optimisation opportunity goes away the moment you have more then one constructor...

Comment: Strangely enough, it looks like both compilers go the [zero-then-mov route](https://godbolt.org/z/2rNpWk) for both `B` and `C` if you actually use the objects.

Comment: If you use both forms of initialisation in the same class, gcc will even assign twice...

Comment: @MilesBudnek Just using it doesn't change it. It's if you have another [static initializer](https://godbolt.org/z/6pZrmc) that can't be inlined (Like `std::ios_base::Init` for streams. But using `printf` inlines it in clang. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/l2Ilj5))

Comment: Is there a reason not to make the relevant constructor `constexpr` to guarantee constant initialization?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is just “yes”, but the reason this is an allowed optimization is worth mentioning.  The implementation is allowed to [initialize anything statically](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Early_dynamic_initialization) if it can prove that certain side effects do not occur at the wrong time as a result.  That analysis can be complicated, which is presumably why GCC doesn’t bother here.